# Django Rest Framework: Not sending email from react form Error 400

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to send a form using the API endpoint beneath. The problem is that I get a 400 error when I use my react based application. If I'm using the api endpoint page it works.
I checked the payload and the only difference seems to be that i'm not sending a csrf token in my react app. So far it was never neccesary when i used model serializers. I believe it is something inside the serializer but i cannot pin it down. Does anyone know what might be causing the 400 error?

sendEmail.js

```
   const testmessage = "This is a test message"
    const testemail = "dsfds@dsfg.de"
    const clientnametest = "name"
    function sendProposal(values) {
        console.log("start sending proposal...");
        setSendProp(true)

        const data = new FormData()
        data.append("Clientname", clientnametest || "");
        data.append("Sender", testemail || "");
        data.append("Message", testmessage || "");

        axios.post(API.email.proposal, data, {

            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
            },
            withCredentials: true,
        })
            .then(res => {


            })
            .finally(() => {                
                setSendProp(false)
            })

        success()
    }
```

views.py

```
class ProposalEmailView(APIView):
    
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = ProposalEmailSerializer
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = ProposalEmailSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer_class.is_valid():
             data = serializer_class.validated_data
             ClientName = data.get('ClientName')
             Sender = data.get('Sender')
             Message = data.get('Message')
             send_mail('Contact Form mail from ' + ClientName,
                       Message, Sender, ['test@test.test'],)
            
             return Response({"success": "Sent"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({"error": "Failed"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

```
class ProposalEmailSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ClientName = serializers.CharField()
    Sender = serializers.EmailField()
    Message = serializers.CharField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it for me. Using the generic views was my issue:

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST',])
def proposal(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        serializer = ProposalEmailSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            ClientName = request.POST['ClientName']
            Sender = request.POST['Sender']
            Message = request.POST['Message']

            # send mail
            send_mail(
                'Contact Form mail from ' + ClientName,
                Message,
                'test@test.domain',
                [Sender],
            )
            # serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```